# On properties and accessors

Tags: objective-c, properties

Assuming that header declaration contains

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) DoublyLinkedList *doublyLinkedList;
```

Is there any difference between

```
[[self doublyLinkedList] release];
[self setDoublyLinkedList:nil];
```

and

```
[doublyLinkedList release];
doublyLinkedList= nil
```

Is one preferred over another? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.

The second option might be ever so slightly faster, because it doesn't use the getter/setter methods.

Just so we're clear, are you retaining doublyLinkedList when you assign it? Because otherwise you're over-releasing.

And unless you have a good reason, I would skip all this and use retain instead of assign, and self.doublyLinkedList = nil to release/clear it.

e.g.

definition

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) DoublyLinkedList *doublyLinkedList;
```

in use

```
self.doublyLinkedList = nil;
```

and on dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc{self.doublyLinkedList=nil;[super dealloc];}
```